# Is it possible to execute a branch as a different user in *nix?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, operating-system, execution, selinux

Is it possible to execute a method as a different user in Linux (or SELinux specifically)? The programs that I have run in individual sandboxes, each with a different user and process id. I have a situation where I have to execute a branch of code as a different user and with different process id to prevent the access of the memory and disk space of the code that's spawning it.

If not possible, can you throw some light on how much of the kernel code has to be changed to achieve it? (I understand its subjective. Alternatively, if you can suggest what and how to go about it, that will be much helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Protecting some resources from other codes executing on the same machine is precisely what lead to the process and UID invention.
If you are searching for a mechanism that looks like a simple function call, I would say it's impossible because it requires the memory to be shared between the caller and the callee. However, using fork/exec (or wrappers like *system()*) will give you some isolation as long as you deal with parameters/results using system objects like *program parameters* or pipes.

Although, the fact that *nix user is meant to protect processes from one-another, requires that an explicit relationship be built between two users to have one user act on behalf of the other.

Actually, you may want to:

- define a sudoers policy which gives the right to your first user to run a command (or a particular command) as the second one.
- use popen() (or system()) in your first program to call the less privileged code.
- if any, pass the parameters and parse the result from stdout

As an extra, you may use the same binary for both executions, this way, all the code can be at the same location.